# How to show a background image over foreground image using CSS

Tags: css

I want to set the background image so that it appears in front of foreground image.

I tried the following code but it is not working as I expected:

```
.background-image
  {
      border :0px;
      background-image: url(/images/icon.png);  
      z-index:1000;      
  }
  .foreground-image
  {
      width:200px;
      height:113px;
      border :0px;
      z-index:1;
  }

<div>
    <a href="#" class="background-image">
        <img class="foreground-image" src="./images/pic1.jpg"  />            
    </a>
</div>
```

I am using CSS2.

Comment: Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: You can't... the clue is in the name: **`background`**`-image`.

Comment: @PatsyIssa - kind of irrelevant here anyway. A child's z-index can't be less than its parent's z-index.

Comment: @j08691 just a side note, regardless of his markup and desired effect he doesn't seem to know that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

If this is your HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="background-image">
        <img class="foreground-image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/100"/>  
    </a>
</div>
```

apply the following CSS rules:

```css
div {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.background-image {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/50);
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
}
.foreground-image {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Set `position: relative` on the image and throw the image deeper into the stacking order by using `z-index: -1`.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/HUK28/

Answer (score 2):

by removing the foreground-image.

```
.background-image {
  border :0;
  background-image: url(/images/icon.png);
  width:200px;
  height:113px;   
  display: block;  
}
.foreground-image {/**/}

<div>
  <a href="#" class="background-image"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 because it made me giggle. Also because it's 100% correctly answering the question that was asked, even though I'm sure that's not what the Asker wanted ;-)

Comment: it started as a joke, but then it turns out it is the only way to do it.

Comment: not strictly true... if you re-arrange the markup (put the `<img />` outside the `<a/>`) then you can overlap them...

Comment: Mark, I can't remove the foreground-image because it's style of image tag inside href. The background image is playicon and the img tag is the image of video